# Why don't US P2P lending companies allow funding from overseas?

Tags: united-states, peer-to-peer-lending

I am living outside of the United States and am interested in investing through peer-to-peer funding companies such as Lending Club.
But I found that they do not allow it to non-US citizens or those who live outside of the United States.

Is there any particular reason for this?

The reason I am asking this is I'm especially interested in investing to individuals or organizations in the United States.

Comment: There are P2P organizations in other countries. Maybe in yours.

Comment: "Is there any particular reason for this?" - money laundering concerns.